# Linear model in R - Multiplication Expression

Tags: r

I have 3 numerical variables `A`, `B` and `C`. I am trying to create a linear model capable of predicting `A`. The expression that I am using is the product of `B*C` in order to predict `A`; however, when looking at the output I am not able to get my equation because I get and extra variable that I don't know what is it.

Here is my code

```
MyData<-read.csv("...", header = T)
head(MyData,6)
str(MyData)

#Linear Model 
#Expersion A= B*C
Model1<-lm(MyData$A~MyData$B*MyData$C)
summary(Model1)
```

Output of `str(MyData)`

```
> str(MyData)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: num  2.5 3.4 2.7 3.6 2.5 2.1
 $ B: num  0.01 0.02 0.015 0.017 0.018 0.01
 $ C: num  0.1 0.2 0.27 0.19 0.17 0.16
```

Output of `summary(Model1)`

```
Call:
lm(formula = MyData$A ~ MyData$B * MyData$C)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.03945 -0.08386 -0.13925  0.67703 -0.40055 -0.01393 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          5.473      5.774   0.948    0.443
MyData$B          -222.431    454.508  -0.489    0.673
MyData$C           -26.482     36.222  -0.731    0.541
MyData$B:MyData$C 1938.961   2679.207   0.724    0.544

Residual standard error: 0.5688 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6149,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.03723 
F-statistic: 1.064 on 3 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.5178
```

`lm` uses the Wilkinson-Rogers notation so `"*"` is an iteration, based on the output, right? is this true, how do I create my model using the product of my two variables?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question -- I don't know which variable you think is "extra" -- but here's a bit that might help:  In R's formula syntax, the asterisk means "include the marginals and the interaction". So `lm(y ~ x1*x2)` is the same thing as `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2)`.  Notice that the colon means "product" in the formula syntax.  If you want just the interaction, use just the colon: `lm(y ~ x1:x2)`.

Comment: @DanY I believe that the extra variable is that  `MyData$B:MyData$C`. So if I replace the `Model1` formula for  `Model1<-lm(MyData$A~B:C)` the actual linear equation should be `A=EstimateB:C*(B*C) + Intercept`, right?

Comment: For formulas, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.3/topics/formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a single term that is the literal product of the two variables, not an interaction, you can use `I()`:

```
Model1 <- lm(MyData$A ~ I(MyData$B * MyData$C))
```

I think in practice, with 2 numeric variables, this ends up the same as Dan's suggestion to use `x1:x2` to get just the interaction without the terms for each individual predictor, but it might differ in other cases.

Comment: For the sake of the discussion, if I introduce a third variable to the equation something like `A= D+(B*C)`, Dan's suggestion won't work?

Comment: No, `lm(A ~ B:C + D)` would be fine, you'd get two terms: (B times C) and D.

Comment: If that is the case, the actual equation would still be `A = EstimateB:C*(B*C)+EstimasteD*D+Intercept`, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're going for, do you want to include `(B * C)` in the equation, without multiplying it by a coefficient? Or in other words, forcing the coefficient for `B * C` to 1?

Comment: I am trying to find the actual equation using the numeric values from the output of `summary()` for this model `lm(A ~ B:C + D)`